# Stack overflow on derefering the value of a register

Tags: rust, stack-overflow

```rust
use std::arch::asm;

fn print_call_stack() {
    let mut fp: u64;
    unsafe {
        asm!(
            "mov {}, rbp",
            out(reg) fp,
        )
    };
    println!("{:#x}", fp);
    let raw = fp as *mut u64;
    fp = unsafe { raw.read_volatile() };
    println!("{:#x}", fp);
}
fn main() {
    print_call_stack();
}
```

I am trying to get the value of rbp register, and derefer the value of it. However, I am getting this stack overflow error. Does anybody know why this happens?

```bash
thread 'main' has overflowed its stack
fatal runtime error: stack overflow
[1]    15344 IOT instruction (core dumped)  cargo run
```

The machine I am running is on x86_64 linux machine, so I am guessing some runtime mechanism to stop the from refering to a value outside the current stack. Am I right?

Comment: How do you know that the top of the stack is a pointer?  If it's just a value (say: 7), then dereferencing it would be bad.

Comment: The `rbp` register is not always used as a frame pointer.  If the compiler doesn't need it for that purpose, it is just another general register and its contents could be anything.

Comment: Remember that optimized builds can and will get rid of in-memory values if the same can be accomplished using registers, pre-computing, or other techniques.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd they're not trying to dereference the *value* on top of the stack, they're trying to dereference the *frame pointer*, which by definition is a pointer, problem is a frame pointer just isn't used in any Rust generated assembly I've seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to look at the [assembly generated by that bit of code](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/3PG1eW83M) (`println` replaced because it generates a lot of unrelated assembly):

```asm
core::hint::black_box:
        mov     qword ptr [rsp - 8], rdi
        lea     rax, [rsp - 8]
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rsp - 8]
        ret

example::print_call_stack:
        sub     rsp, 24

        mov     rax, rbp

        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 8], rax
        mov     rdi, qword ptr [rsp + 8]
        call    qword ptr [rip + core::hint::black_box@GOTPCREL]
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rsp + 8]
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rax]
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 16], rax
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rsp + 16]
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 8], rax
        mov     rdi, qword ptr [rsp + 8]
        call    qword ptr [rip + core::hint::black_box@GOTPCREL]
        add     rsp, 24
        ret

example::main:
        push    rax
        call    qword ptr [rip + example::print_call_stack@GOTPCREL]
        pop     rax
        ret
```

you'll quickly realize that your assumptions were simply wrong.
`rbp` is *not* used as the frame pointer, in fact that code doesn't even touch `rbp` except for reading it into your variable, so it essentialy reads and dereferences a indeterminate value.

Comment: So if I want to enable `rbp` as the frame pointer, compiling using `rustc`, how would I enable it?

Comment: You can't that's just not something supported.

Comment: I am not sure, I did try the flag `-Cforce-frame-pointers=yes`, and now the frame pointer is there. 
```bash

Comment: Seem like, it would be hard to get the call stack information based on this [link](https://rcore--os-cn.translate.goog/rCore-Tutorial-Book-v3/chapter1/8answer.html?_x_tr_sch=http&_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=vi&_x_tr_pto=wapp). So I think this might not an easy way to backtrace on rust.

Comment: @Dlwlrma1605 is this what you're looking for? https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/backtrace/index.html

Comment: Not really, I have used this [link](https://docs.rs/libunwind-sys/latest/libunwind_sys/) to print out the call stack.